# Evaluate the following integral without using the error function

Tags: gamma-function

Evaluate $\int_0^{\infty } e^{-2 a x-x^2}  dx$ without using error function

Comment: This is going to be interesting (for me, at least): *without* the error function...

Comment: There's no elementary closed form for this integral if $a\neq 0$. One could write down an infinite series expansion, but this is the same as what the error function would give you.

Answer (score 1):

Why so adamant about no error function? Completing the square in the exponential you have
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^{\infty} e^{-x^2 - 2ax} dx = \sqrt{\pi}e^{a^2}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}e^{-(x+a)^2}dx.
\end{align}
$$
So the second term is just the Gaussian with location $-a$ and scale $1$, so there really isn't any closed form and the question just reduces to deriving approximations on the tails of Gaussians, which is another question entirely but see something like https://arxiv.org/abs/1012.2063